# Multi GPU passthrough failed

Tags: gpu, qemu, pci

My server has 4 PCI slots, their addresses are 0000:04:00.0, 0000:05:00.0, 0000:41:00.0, 0000:42:00.0.

I want to pass 4 GPUs to virtual machines via vfio, each of the VMs has one GPU.

VMs worked fine when I passed 0000:04:00.0 and 0000:05:00.0 to VMs or passed 0000:41:00.0 and 0000:42:00.0 to VMs.

But VMs which used 0000:41:00.0 and 0000:42:00.0 had no output to the screen and I could not ping VM's ip when I passed 0000:04:00, 0000:41:00.0 and 0000:42:00.0 to VMs, but the VM which used 0000:04:00 worked fine.

I got the same result when I passed 0000:05:00, 0000:41:00.0 and 0000:42:00.0 to VMs:  VM with 0000:05:00 worked fine and VMs which used 0000:41:00.0 and 0000:42:00.0 hanged.

When I define 0000:04:00.0 and 0000:05:00.0 as group A, 0000:41:00.0 and 0000:42:00.0 as group B, the result is:

1. VMs work fine When I just pass group A or group B to vms.
2. Just group A works fine when the gpus that I pass to vms contain group A and B.

In case 2, VMs work fine when I used '-vga cirrus' instead of '-vga none'. But I get code 12 from graphics card in Device Manager of windows 7. And this is not what I want, I just want to use the graphics card in the host, so I should use '-vga none'.

It also worked fine when I remove VGA passthrough or just pass 0000:41:00.1 (the HDMI audio of graphics card) to VM.

I got no error output in qemu monitor.

**How can I solve this probem?**

Version of qemu:

```
QEMU emulator version 2.5.1.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Qemu command:

```
/root/qemu25/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name gputest_41 \
-machine q35,accel=kvm,usb=off,smm=off \
-cpu host \
-m 4096 \
-realtime mlock=off \
-smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
-no-user-config \
-nodefaults  \
-rtc base=localtime \
-no-shutdown \
-boot strict=on \
-device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e \
-device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.1,addr=0x1 \
-drive file=/root/gpu/gputest_41/win7.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2 \
-device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.2,addr=0x2,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 \
-k en-us \
-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.2,addr=0x4 \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=41:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,romfile=/root/nvidia/gt710.rom,x-vga=on \
-msg timestamp=on \
-vga none \
-cpu host,hv_vendor_id=1234567890ab,kvm=off \
-net nic,model=virtio \
-net tap,ifname=tap1,script=/root/qemu/qemu-ifup.sh,downscript=/root/qemu/qemu-ifdown.sh \
-monitor stdio
```

System info:

```
Linux ns.mqcache.net 4.2.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Aug 30 21:25:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of lspci -vvv:

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 15
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Region 3: Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at ec80 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at d9000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nouveau

05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 14
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at d9ffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 25.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


41:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 15
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at b8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 98000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128M]
    Region 3: Memory at a6000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at bc80 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b9000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nouveau

41:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 14
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at b9ffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 25.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

After starting vm:
    lspci -vvv

```
    05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 102
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Region 3: Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at ec80 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at d9000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nouveau

05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 101
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at d9ffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 25.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


    41:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 104
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at b8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 98000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Region 3: Memory at a6000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at bc80 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b9000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nouveau

41:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2929
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 103
    NUMA node: 1
    Region 0: Memory at b9ffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 25.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```